# Does the file closes in c when the function returns?

Tags: c, file-handling

I am checking the existence of a file in a function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  foo(argc, argv);
  // File exists
  // Do something
}

void foo(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int f = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if(f == -1)
  {
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Does the file go out of scope or closes when the function call returns or will it stay open and affect the performance as I am writing a c code to copy the contents of one file to another with system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file doesn't close since there's no code to close it. The file doesn't go out of scope because only a variable or object can go out of scope. However, when `f` goes out of scope, the descriptor (or handle) used to access the file goes out of scope leaving no way to access or close it.

Comment: Re “The file doesn't go out of scope because only a variable or object can go out of scope”: Objects cannot “go out of scope.” Only identifiers have scope. Objects have lifetimes.

Comment: Then I will have to do `close(f);`. Right?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't find parsing terminology this tightly to be useful. If someone has `struct foo s;` in their code, I think it's useful to say that while `s` is in scope, `s` is an object whose lifetime continues until it goes out of scope. It's not wrong to say `s` is an identifier that identifies an object, I just don't demand that level of indirection in speech or communication as it's not useful to be so picky.

Comment: @Ahmn21 To release any resources associated with the open file (such as the descriptor), you need to pass the descriptor's value to `close`. That will cause the implementation to release those resources.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Wrong terminology teaches wrong ideas. The identifier and the object are different things, and they differ in the places and times they can be used. Things that are taught wrong cause problems, result in information that must be unlearned, and the correct information has to be learned. So it does not save time or provide a benefit and is not useful.